# has-text-centered of Bulma does not work well

Tags: html, css, bulma

I tried centering my content using `has-text-centered` of [Bulma](https://bulma.io/).
But "Hello" is a little bit off to the left. Why?

My Code:

```
<div class="columns is-multiline">
<div class="column is-2"><p class="notification is-primary has-text-centered">Hello</p></div>
</div>
```

[My Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZZNN.png)

Comment: because "notification" in p tag set padding like this : padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem 1.25rem 1.5rem; , so padding is not right both side that's why not in center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In notification class there is "padding:1.25rem 2.5rem 1.25rem 1.5rem" you need to change it to this "padding: 1.25rem 1.5rem 1.25rem 1.5rem".

Answer (score 0):

Check this post. **has-text-centered** is a class so you need to give the property to that particular class means **text-align: centre;** for centre align if you want the text on left so use **text-align: left;** for left align in **has-text-left** class.

```css
.is-multiline {
  background-color: #00d1b2;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.has-text-centered {
  text-align: center;
} 

.has-text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.has-text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns is-multiline">
<div class="column is-2"><p class="notification is-primary has-text-centered">Hello</p></div>
</div>
```